# Regex - discard text after comma character

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

If I have the text:

```
test: firstString, blah: anotherString, blah:lastString
```

How can I get the text "firstString"

My regex is:

```
 test:(.*),
```

**EDIT**
Which brings back `firstString, blah: anotherString,` but I only need to bring back the text 'firstString'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
test:(.*?),
```

Or a character class:

```
test:([^,]*),
```

To ignore the comma as well:

```
test:([^,]*)
```

If you'd like to omit the `test:` as well you can use a look-behind like this:

```
(?<=test:\s)[^,]*
```

Since you're using this [grok debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/), I was able to get this to work by using a named capture group:

```
(?<test>(?<=test:\s)[^,]*)
```

Comment: this is bring back the text "test: firstString" how can I get just the "firstString"?

Comment: @user86834 Just extract the first capture group: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)

Comment: I'm not using the Java API for this one.

Comment: @user86834 I assumed since the question is tagged with Java, you were using the Java API. What are you using instead?

Comment: @user86834 Well, I'm not familiar with that at all, but you could try using a look-behind: `(?<=test:\s*)[^,]*`

Comment: This is the best i have which is very close, there is just a colon to omit: (?<test>(:([^,]*)))

Comment: @user86834 After playing around in the debugger, I got a pattern that worked. See my updated answer.